# Need Superuser access on Jasperserver Using CAS

Tags: cas, jasperserver

I'm running Jasperserver 5.0.1 and have integrated it with CAS
(I used this Guide http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/integrating-cas-jasperreports-server)

Now I can't sign into jasperserver using the regular login screen

And If I sign in using CAS I am not Superuser

NOTE:
jasperadmin & superuser, usernames have been setup in CAS and If I log in using these I still don't have "ROLE_SUPERUSER" permission

So my question is: After Implementing CAS how do I login as a Superuser ?